# use org tags inline?

Tags: org-mode, org-tags

Is it possible to use org mode tags `:LIKE_THIS:` inline in the heading text, the way `#twitter_style` tags are used elsewhere?

If I add any text after a `:tag:`, it stops being highlighted as a tag, and <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-q</kbd> stops to recognize it, too.

On the other hand, I would like to avoid duplicating text in a header, like below:

`*** TODO Make foo use bar           :foo:bar:`

Comment: Open up an `org-mode` buffer and familiarize yourself with the *variable* `org-complex-heading-regexp` to get a feel for how it is that `org-mode` knows what to do with a heading, and you'll see that tags need to be in a special location with a special format.  The regex gets set up when the buffer loads taking into consideration things like `org-todo-keywords`.  Search utilities that generate the `*Org Agenda*` buffer rely upon specific locations of tags.  People sometimes opt to put something *similar* to tags in the property drawers since `org-tags-view` can also search that location.

Comment: @lawlist: Please turn it into an answer. (The answer would be negative.)

Comment: The OP was 4+ years ago, and to my knowledge, inline tags are not supported (yet). I'd like to resurface the question and expand on it. In my use-case, the need for inline tags has come up repeatedly. In fact, it is desirable to include inline tags not only in the header, but also in the body underneath a header. The format could be `:tag:` or perhaps something different (e.g., `#tag` or `@tag`) to distinguish the behavior (and programmatic utilization) of inline tags from standard `:tags:`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`org-mode` does not support placing inline tags within the heading, except those that appear at the very end of the heading.

I suggest opening up an `org-mode` buffer and familiarizing oneself with the variable `org-complex-heading-regexp` to get a feel for how it is that `org-mode` knows what to do with a heading, and see that tags need to be in a special location with a special format. That regex gets set up when the buffer loads taking into consideration things like `org-todo-keywords`. Search utilities that generate the `*Org Agenda*` buffer rely upon specific locations of tags. People sometimes opt to put something *similar* to tags in the property drawers since `org-tags-view` can also search that location.  [fn1]

[fn1] See the "**Property Searches**" advanced searching section of the `org-mode` tutorial section http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html

Comment: I've tried to implement this functionality, with hashtag style `#tags`, with limited success: https://github.com/incandescentman/org-inline-tags